# Polymer 1.0 - display youtube video like the Google I/O site header

Tags: youtube, polymer

I am using `Polymer Elements 1.0` and I want to implement a youtube video like they did at https://events.google.com/io2015/ in the header.
I see that they used:

```
<div class="play__button__container" on-tap="{{openMastheadVideo }}" data-link-track="home-watch-keynote-masthead"><h5>Watch the keynote</h5> </div>
```

But nothing in Polymer Catalog that helps me understand this.

I tried using `google-youtube` but I can't use the material designed play button...instead the default youtube playbutton is used. Also, I want to do the video full screen horizontally and about 400px vertically. But when I use

```
  <google-youtube
    video-id="YMWd8E"
    height="400px"
    width="100%"
    rel="0"
    start="5"
    playsinline="0"
    controls="0"
    showinfo="0"
    autoplay="0">
  </google-youtube>
```

It zooms into the video still rather than proportionally displaying it like the google i/o site header with the speaker holding the microphone.

Any suggestions on how I can make my youtube video display look like the one in the https://events.google.com/io2015/ header?